# react-virtualized Table dynamic column width with CellMeasurer

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

Can i implement somehow functionality of CellMeasurer to react-virtualized Table component?

I want to have dynamic column width.

Comment: I solved it!
CellMeasurer needs `CellMeasurerCache`
You need to add event handler on resizing columns:

```const resizeColumnHandler = () => {
    cellMeasurerCache.clearAll()
    table.current.recomputeRowHeights()
  }
```

Comment: I think I have the same issue, but I'm not sure how you fixed your issue. Each row in my table has cells dynamically sized, but this means my columns don't line up!